# Ivory Search [pluggin WP] How it works?

Tags: wordpress

I installed the Ivory Search plugin and I'm trying to understand how it works! I read the doc and saw some videos but it seems that I don't have any result fields appearing on my side! Did I forget to configure something somewhere?
When I write a word and I validate nothing happens...
In the example of my search (on the image), the word does exist on an article on the site, but nothing happens!

```
<div>
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[ivory-search id="201" title="Default Search Form"]'); ?>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't meet the purposes of this site defined in the [help]. It might be better to look for a support forum for the plugin, or a general Wordpress help group.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the plugin and make sure that you didn't messed up with default settings....hope this thing

Comment: thank you ! I'll try, but I don't think it changes anything because I didn't change anything from the basic settings except a little css, and I had tested the plugin before my css modifications